# Escaping @ syntax in comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use @ signs in comments without invoking comment replies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102327/how-can-i-use-signs-in-comments-without-invoking-comment-replies)

What is the syntax to refer to "@word" in a comment without it being interpretted as a reply as a user name?

I tried looking in the Markdown help and couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Use backticks to escape it.

Comment: Related: [Should we discourage the use of multiple redundant @username pings in comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615)

Comment: @Ben It is duplicate. Would it be possible to tag that question with [markdown] and [comment-replies] to make it easier to find?

Comment: Seems reasonable :-). Done

Comment: Did you run into [that warning](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-use-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings-in-comments/2615#2615) *"Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified"*, or were you just wondering? If the warning was unclear, then maybe that needs some change. (Though it's already quite long, being it shown in [a vertical way](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zZFvh.png).)